# Limit of Multivariate Probability Density Function as one or more or all variables approach positive or negative infinity

Tags: real-analysis, limits, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

Could someone point out a good source or provide justification as to whether the limit of a multivariate probability density function, as one or more or all variables tends to positive or negative infinity, goes to zero.

$$\lim_{x_{1}\to\pm\infty}f(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n})=0$$

$$\lim_{x_{1},x_{2}\to\pm\infty}f(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n})=0$$

$$\lim_{x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}\to\pm\infty}f(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n})=0$$

I have found this related question for the univariate case: [Limit of probability density function as random variable approaches +/- infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663758/limit-of-probability-density-function-as-random-variable-approaches-infinity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is in general no guarantee, that the limits exists.** If the limits exist, they all have to be zero.

*Proof:* 
Assume that 
$$\lim_{x_{1}\to\infty}f(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n})=a>0$$
then by definition of limit there exist $0<\epsilon<a$ and $\hat x_1>0$ such that 
$f(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n})>\epsilon ~ \forall x_1 > \hat x_1$ and any $x_2,\ldots,x_n$. But then 
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}) d(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}) 
& \geq 
\int_{\hat x_1}^{\infty}  \int_{\mathbb R^{n-1} } f(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}) d(x_{2},...,x_{n})d(x_{1} ) \\ 
& \geq \epsilon . \infty = \infty 
\end{align}
so the you see that measure of the whole space is not $1$ and that is contradiction with $f$ beeing density. Therefore 
$$\lim_{x_{1}\to\infty}f(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n})=0.$$
You can do the others pretty same way.

But as I have stated, there is no guarantee that the limits exist. You can for example take any continuous 1 dimensional density function $f$ and define 
\begin{align}
g(x) & = f(x) &\text{if } x\neq n, n\in \mathbb N, \\
g(x) & = 1 &\text{if }x =  n, n\in \mathbb N. 
\end{align}
Then $g$ is density function with countable many incontinuities, but the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}g(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the integrals and the inequalities? Also if the limit does not exist, I suppose the values the random variable can take will not reach +/- infinity? or the set of possibilities does not include +/- infinity; Is that true?

Comment: @user249613 We know that density is nonnegative function therefore  $\int_{\mathbb R ^n } f(x)dx \geq \int_{A} f(x)dx $ for any $A \subset \mathbb R ^n$. We defined $A=\{ (x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb R ^n: x_1 \geq \hat x_1 \}$ and from definition of limit we know that $f \geq \epsilon > 0$ on this set (that is how we defined $\hat x_1$). But the Lebesgue measure of this set is $\infty$  and the integral of positive function over set with infinite measure is infinite.

Comment: @user249613 I am sorry I am not sure I understand your second question. But you can "redefine"  the density in any points, which belongs to the set of zero measure without changing the random variable (that is how I did the last counterexample). So if I take my $g$ and redefine it such that $g(x) = n \Leftrightarrow x=n, n \in \mathbb R$ then $g$ is still density function, $\lim_{n\in \mathbb N,n\rightarrow \infty}g(n)=\infty$ but $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}g(x)$ does not exist.