# $f$ and $f '$ are in $L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R}) $ then $lim f(x)=0 $ when $x\rightarrow +\infty and -\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have this question , how to prove that :

when $f$ and $f '$ are in $L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R}) $ then $lim f(x)=0$ when $x\rightarrow +\infty $and$   -\infty$ ?

thanks ......

Comment: Not true, the limit does not need to exist.

Comment: @iiivooo Without the requirement on $f'$, I would absolutely agree, but given $f'\in L^1$, it is harder to come up with a counterexample. Do you have one?

Comment: There is no requirement that this function is continuous in every $x$, also function from $L^1$ can be undefined on set of zero measure! So you can think about function $f$ such that $f,f' \in L^1$ and  $f(n) = n$ for each $n \in \mathbb N$. So the function $f'$  is undefined on set of measure 0.

Comment: @ iiivooo but in this case it wont be bounded !

Comment: @M.luffy don't want to edit my comment, but construct the same counterexample with $f(n) = 1$ for each $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Is $f$ differentiable everywhere?

Comment: @zhw. That needs clarification... I would have assumed so.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean $f$ is differentiable everywhere, then the answer is yes: Since $f'$ is bounded, $f$ is Lipschitz, hence uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R.$ But a uniformly continuous function in $L^1(\mathbb R)$ must tend to $0$ at $\pm \infty.$

Comment: Yes, exactly and to prove it you can use the same technique as in my [answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1702608/limit-of-multivariate-probability-density-function-as-one-or-more-or-all-variabl/1702638#1702638).

Comment: @  zhw well  can you  tell me what doese it mean $f \in C(\mathbb{R}^+,L^1(\mathbb{R}))$ ?  for example $f(t,x)\in C(\mathbb{R}^+,L^1(\mathbb{R}))$ ? doese this mean that $lim \int_\mathbb{R}|f(t,x)-f(t_0,x)|dx=0 when t\rightarrow t_0$ this condition on f exist too, i know that my question is not really clear because i am in a demonstration of a theorem and i can not write every thing from the begening  :) !

Comment: @M.luffy Not sure about your question.