# If a probability density function has a limit at infinity, is that limit always zero?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

I just read a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663758/limit-of-probability-density-function-as-random-variable-approaches-infinity) which showed that probability density functions do not always have a limit of zero as a variable approaches infinity because they don't always have a limit at infinity.

Given that a probability density function has a limit at infinity, is that limit always zero? If so, is there a rigorous and formal proof that shows this property?

---

Update:

I just found another [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1702608/limit-of-multivariate-probability-density-function-as-one-or-more-or-all-variabl), which is a generalization of what I'm asking to the multivariate case. In a mathematical sense, this makes my question a duplicate.

---

Comment: Yes, because a pdf is a function in $L^1(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: How else could one satisfy $\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(X=x) \;dx =1$ and $P(X=x)\ge 0$?

Comment: @Semoi, that's what my intuition was as well. To clarify, I'm looking for a rigorous explanation that shows why it is true, which may or may not directly reference the properties from the definition of a probability density function that you mentioned.

Comment: I see someone downvoted my question. Please comment when possible on how I could improve the question.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the only thing I can think of is that your last sentence seems (even with the "Please") a little demanding, as if you were a professor asking a class to do something.  It might be slightly better if it read something like "Is there a formal and rigorous demonstration of why it is true?"  But I'm really just guessing.

Comment: Anyway: Suppose that the PDF $f(x)$ observes $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = a > 0$.  Then there exists an $x_0$ such that for all $x > x_0$, $f(x) > a/2$.  That means that the corresponding CDF $F(x)$ must have, for all $x > x_0$, a slope of at least $a/2$, which means that $F(x + 2/a) > F(x) + 1$.  But $F(x)$ must observe $0 \leq F(x) \leq 1$, which yields a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @BrianTung, I've updated the question to have a new phrasing.

Comment: @BrianTung, would you elaborate a little more on where $$\exists x_0 | \forall x > x_0\ f(x) > \frac{a}{2} $$ comes from? I might be missing some background knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be proven by contradiction.

A pdf function must satisfy the following
$$f(x)\geq0\quad\forall x\in\Bbb R\tag1$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\mathrm dx=1\tag2$$
Suppose $f(x)\geq0$ with
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=a>0$$
By definition of the limit, for all $\epsilon\geq0$, there exist an $N\in\Bbb R$ such that if $x>N$ then
$\lvert f(x)-a\rvert<\epsilon$

Let's take $\epsilon=\frac a2>0$, then there exist $N_0$ such that if $x>N_0$ then
$$\lvert f(x)-a\rvert<\frac a2$$
which implies
$$\frac a2<f(x)<\frac {3a}2$$
Now
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\mathrm dx&\geq
\int_{N_0}^{+\infty}f(x)\mathrm dx\\&\geq\int_{N_0}^{+\infty}\frac a2\mathrm dx\\&\geq+\infty
\end{align}
This contradict our second condition. If a function has a limit at infinity that is not $0$, then the function is not a probability densité function.